# SEO for book site

Tags: seo

I'm building a book site. I have pages that contain information about individual books. Here's what I have done so far:

- `<title>` has the book's complete title. I will be adding a "- Company Name" to the end of it soon
- the URL has the book's complete title, hyphenated (dashed), with the ISBN at the end of it
- The meta description will have the book's description

The page the user sees also has the book's title, ISBN, description + some other details.

Just for these types of pages, what have I done right? Wrong? And what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me.

The ISBN number will make the TITLE unique - but may be unnecessary and also arbitrarily lengthen the title (which should be as short but meaningful as uniquely possible)

In place of the ISBN, i'd consider including the Author's name.

Comment: which do you think is better: `www.domain.com/book-title/isbn-number/` or `www.domain.com/book-title-isbn-number/`?

Comment: I have a personal preference for only adding nested-levels for sub-folder information, so bear that in mind - my preference would be (out of those two) `www.domain.com/book-title-isbn-number/` - but I still feel you're going to get better SEO and consumer value by including the author - e.g. `www.domain.com/authors-name/book-title` (followed by `-isbn-number` if you must...

Answer (score 1):

You've done the on-page part, now to the important part... inbound links. Your pages could contain nothing but a picture of a moose, if they had enough of the right inbound links they would be #1.